# Openlayers Map in React not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gis, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers in React to display a map. The issue is that the map is being loaded for the whole size of the div but the map tiles cannot cover the entire height and width of the map canvas.
e.g. here the white part should have been covered with those layers as well, but it isn't plus when a draw on the white part as shown in the last image the polyline feature is being drawn on that small map.

[image: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ity7c.jpg)]

More examples: [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCvpX.jpg); [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTQNh.png)

I want the layers to cover the whole div, but I cannot do it by myself as OpenLayers automatically should have done that maybe? Please help with this, I don't know much since I am a beginner.

Comment: Please view the images on new page as I am unable to post them because of zero reputation.

Comment: Re you resizing the div programmatically or changing its visibility?  If so you may need to call `map.updateSize();` after doing that.  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize

Comment: @Mike thanks for your reply but the issue was with css.

Comment: @SI_RG - welcome to SO! If you have managed to resolve this issue, please post the answer for others. Did you fix the issue by loading the OL CSS?

Comment: @LeeGoddard Hey! No it was a css issue where I was setting the width of the map's container div to be 100% so when accessed through mobile it was giving these small maps ...